# Convert Database To XML with Specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have database with two tables: `Transaction` and `from_person`.

I need to convert it to specified format like this:

```
<transaction>                      
  <transaction_number>TRNWEB0147</transaction_number
  <transaction_location>felesteen</transaction_location>
  <date_transaction>2016-05-25T00:00:00</date_transaction>
  <from_funds_code>C</from_funds_code>
<from_person>                    
  <gender>M</gender>
  <title>Mr.</title>
  <first_name>Mohamed</first_name>
  <middle_name>Mohamed</middle_name>
  <prefix>AHMED</prefix>
  <last_name>yahia</last_name>
  <birth_date>1984-11-16T00:00:00</birth_date>
  <ssn>28411160225124</ssn>
</from_person>
</transaction>
```

I try to do this query:

```
select tr.transactionnumber
      ,tr.transaction_location
      ,tr.transaction_description
      ,tr.date_transaction
      ,tr.teller
      ,tr.authorized
      ,tr.transmode_
      ,tr.amount_local
      ,(select fp.from_funds_code
              ,fp.from_country
          from from_person fp
         where fp.from_funds_code = tr.t_from_my_client
           for xml path(''), elements, type)
  from dbo. [ transaction ] tr
   for xml path(''), elements, type
```

but result become in this format:

```
  <transaction_number>TRNWEB0147</transaction_number
  <transaction_location>felesteen</transaction_location>
  <date_transaction>2016-05-25T00:00:00</date_transaction>
  <from_funds_code>C</from_funds_code>              
  <gender>M</gender>
  <title>Mr.</title>
  <first_name>Mohamed</first_name>
  <middle_name>Mohamed</middle_name>
  <prefix>AHMED</prefix>
  <last_name>yahia</last_name>
  <birth_date>1984-11-16T00:00:00</birth_date>
  <ssn>28411160225124</ssn>
```

I tried many ways but not succeed, please help.

Comment: Have you tried setting `for xml path('from_person')` in your subquery?

Comment: no what you mean? need more detail ?

Comment: *"A Subquery or Inner query or Nested query is a query within another SQL query"* (quoted from tutorialspoint.com - [SQL - Sub Queries](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm)). You have only one. In that subquery you use `FOR XML PATH('')`. Try `FOR XML PATH('from_person')`.

Comment: i know what mean subquery 
but it's Done Excellent by adding my missed line that you added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this query.

```
SELECT transaction_number,transaction_location,date_transaction,from_funds_code,
(
    SELECT gender,title,first_name,middle_name,prefix,last_name,birth_date,ssn
    FROM from_person FP
    WHERE FP.FROM_FUNDS_CODE  =TR.T_FROM_MY_CLIENT 
    FOR XML PATH('from_person'), ELEMENTS, TYPE 
)
FROM dbo.[TRANSACTION] TR
FOR XML PATH('transaction'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```